# Facebook "Send to Messenger" button is not displaying for a logged out user

Tags: php, facebook, messenger

I am having a webpage developed in php which has "Send to Messenger" button.

I have set up the button by following the guidelines specified in my Facebook developer account.

I have made the domain whitelisted, created a Facebook page, generated access token, and set up the Webhook correctly.

And the button does display properly for the logged in users.

But for the users who do not log in to Facebook, the button doesn't show up.

Please tell me what to do to display the button for the logged out users also?

Comment: How is this related to PHP? Is there any code involved that you want to share?

Comment: I meant I am having a php page in which I have a "Send to Messenger" button using the following code:

Comment: <div class="fb-send-to-messenger" messenger_app_id="262********" page_id="100***"  data-ref="123456" cta_text="Send_to_Messenger" color="blue" size="standard">
    </div>

Comment: Pleae add all clarification to your quesiton by editing it. Additionally, the given code does not contain any PHP code

Comment: Actually I have a php page which has some database functionality. In which I am having the "Send to Messenger" button also.

Comment: The button does displays for the logged in users. But it doesnt get displayed for the logged out users. I am not sure why.

Comment: Yes. Somehow I found out the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. For the users who have logged out from Facebook, the "Send to Messenger" button will not get displayed.
2. For the users who have logged in their Facebook account but if they are not an admin, we need to submit the review for the APP (created using Facebook developer account) to display the button for them.
3. For the user, who has logged in their Facebook account and if they are the admin of the APP, then the button will be displayed properly.